# Selenium: Upload file for input type =- 'button'

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am trying to upload a file into a file upload button.

The input element has a type of 'button' not 'file'.
HTML:

```
<input class="btn jsSelectFile" type="button" value="Select file"/>
```

As a result when using `SendKeys()`, the file upload does not work.
I call the below snippet:

`Browser.FindElement(By.XPath(XPath)).SendKeys(path);`

It simply brings up the browser file window and does not select the file.

Does anyone know how to upload file for above input type? Thanks.

Comment: HTML of element is: <input class="btn jsSelectFile" type="button" value="Select file"/>

Comment: This is not a file tag.Are you sure there is no file tag?

Comment: I also run into this situation without type=file to send the files in.
<input id="diff-file" type="button" value="Select"></input>

Comment: _It simply brings up the browser file window and does not select the file._  I had this effect at some time, too, using relative file paths. It worked with absolute file paths.

Comment: I used the absolute file path but it did not work to send the file into the button element.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 choices.

1. Use the robot class that simulates keyboard actions e.g

   driver.findElement(By.id("SWFUpload_0")).click();
   Robot r = new Robot();
   r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_C);        // C
   r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_C);
   r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_COLON);    // : (colon)
   r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_COLON);
   r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SLASH);    // / (slash)
   r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SLASH);
   // etc. for the whole file path

   r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);    // confirm by pressing Enter in the end
   r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);

   2. Add a input field with type="file"W over the input button and simply set the optacity to 0% so the element is not shown to the user and they think they are selecting the button. Then you will be able to send the file location. See http://www.zamzar.com/ for an example of this